# Difference between *.1.gz and *.1posix.gz files (UNIX manpages)

Tags: linux, unix, posix, manpage

I am working on a project regarding UNIX manpages, and I realized that some of them exist in pairs of the form `<utility name>.1.gz` and `<utility name>.1posix.gz`.

Why are there two manpages about the same utility (I am mainly interested in section 1)? Which one does the `man` command opens? I opened and read both files for `bc`, for example, and it seems to open the `bc.1.gz` file, but is this a general rule? Is basic behavioral information (e.g. error codes) always located in one of them?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: The default section order is `1 n l 8 3 2 3posix 3pm 3perl 3am 5 4 9 6 7` ... oddly, that doesn't mention `1posix` ... possibly not needed since the only reason `3` is split is to make `2` appear over `3posix, since the syscall-vs-library distinction isn't in posix?

Answer (score 0):

From the posix man page for man (1P)  it says;

This  manual  page  is part of the POSIX Programmer's Manual.  The Linux implementation of this interface may differ (consult the corresponding Linux  manual  page  for  details  of Linux behavior), or the interface may not be implemented on Linux.

ref[The man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/man/)